# import from "library" vs "library/part"

Tags: typescript

This might have been asked before, but I don't know exactly what to search for.

Is there any differences/benefits to use either?

```
import { myModule } from "myLibrary";
```

or

```
import { myModule } from "myLibrary/myLibraryPart";
```

And when `typescript` compiles code, does it include entire library or only the parts of the library that's being used?

Answer (score 0):

Module loading is a little bit tricky and can be configured through your config file.

You can find more about how typescript loads modules here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only

And here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Basically the compiler depending on your configuration will walk up looking for your module to import.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't cover neither of the questions...